# Alternatives for parsing sql query

Tags: sql-server, parsing, audit

I have an audit running on multiple tables in my database that is triggered when a user runs a select against said tables.  I am attempting to parse the 'statement' returned from the audit and get a username out of the information.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT LastName,
              queryLastName,
              statement,
              Event_time  AS CurrentDateTime,
              'AuditFile' AS SourceTable
       FROM   (SELECT statement,
                      event_time,
                      SUBSTRING(server_principal_name, 9, len(server_principal_name) - 8)                                                                                                               AS LastName,
                      SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(statement, CHARINDEX('LastName like ''%', statement) + 16, 20), 0, CHARINDEX('%''', SUBSTRING(statement, CHARINDEX('LastName like ''', statement) + 16, 20))) AS queryLastName
               FROM   #MyTempTable
               WHERE  server_principal_name != 'abc'
                      AND CHARINDEX('LastName like ''%', statement) > 0) AS A) AS B
WHERE  querylastname != ''
```

Now, the above query will correctly return any SELECT query that has Lastname like '%name%', but i'd also like to be able to return names looked up in other ways such as '%name' or '_name__'.  Are there any more elegant solutions to solve this problem?

Edit: The Audit file contains a column called 'Statement'.  This holds what the query was that triggered the audit.  For example,

```
SELECT * from tblUserNames where LastName Like '%Smith%'
```

will trigger the audit and place the above query in statement.
My query takes Smith out of the string however if a user entered '%Smith' instead, the query would not work as it does not pick up variations.  Same goes for 'Smith', '*Smith*' etc.  If possible, I need a more elegant way to handle multiple situations where a user could look up a name using wildcards on either end of the name.

Comment: Is this SqlServer or MySQL ? You tagged both.

Comment: My mistake (obviously).  It is Sql Server.

Comment: Give example data and desired results.

Comment: Use Regex :) All LIKE patterns in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: Makes sense. like '[%_]%[%_]' seems to work properly and I can write another query to handle 'name'. Thank you.